# Codeception into another directory

Tags: php, codeception

I created a custom component loaded by Composer.

Here is the structure of my code when my component is loaded.

- MyProject

  - vendor

    - myComponent

---

AFTER that, I created the file `myComponentTest.php` to run an unit test with Codeception.

- MyProject

  - tests

    - myComponentTest.php
  - vendor

    - myComponent

It works very well with the command :

> ./vendor/bin/codecept run

Alright. Nothing special about it. The Codeception test is ok ! :)

---

But I guess the procedure is wrong, the file `myComponentTest.php` should be in to the `vendor/myComponent` directory, am I right ?

Because, this unit test is only related to the component. For example, If I decide to remove the component, it won't remove my `myComponentTet.php` file, so I'll have some error when I'll run my unit tests.

BUT, if I move my `MyComponentTest.php` into the `vendor/myComponent` directory, I won't be able to run this test, because the Codeception command only execute tests from the `tests` directory.

So what should I do please ? I'm confused about that. Thanks.

Comment: There is no reason to run tests from vendor directory.
You should make your component a separate composer library and run its tests when you work on that library, not when you work on your app.

Answer (score 0):

See how testing is implemented in projects with sub-projects in [Yii2 framework](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/codeception.yml)

codeception.yml in root project directory

```
include:
    - common
    - frontend
    - backend
paths:
    log: console/runtime/logs
settings:
    colors: true
```

Where common|frontend|backend directory with codeception.yml files

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nope it doesn't help, sorry about that. But thanks for trying. And I do using Yii2 framework, you're right about it.

I'm not looking for some code btw, I'm just looking for a good procedure. 

So, basically I can resume my question with this way :
- should I put my testComponent.php file into the vendor or the test directory ?
=> if it's the vendor directory, how can I test it by using Codeception ?
=> if it's the test directory, what happened if I remove my component from the vendors ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that you need create tests directory in your module directory, in the root of the module you should make the file codeception.yml, and in the main file include module directory